# Need help using routes for socket.io

Tags: node.js

I am new to Node.js, and I am trying to configure my route in the server1.js file.

When I go to my `localhost:3000/socket.html` it does not read the case for `socket.html` instead it goes straight to the default case.

However when I output the the path on the console log.. I see the path is correctly outputted which is `/socket.html`

I am really confused and don't understand why its not reaching that case statement.

Any help would be really appreciated. Below is the code I am using.

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');


var server =  http.createServer(function(request,response){

    console.log('Connection');
   var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;

   console.log(path); //Shows the correct path in console


    switch(path){

     //This case statement works 
        case '/':

    response.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    response.write('hello world');
    break;

  //It doesn't reach this case statement
    case 'socket.html':


    fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error,data) {

        if(error){
            response.writeHead(404);
            resonse.write("oops this file doesn't exist - 404");
        } else {
            response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type" : "text/html"});
            response.write(data,"utf8");
        }

    });

        console.log('socket path');

    break;

    default : 
    response.writeHead(404);
    response.write("oops this doesn't exist - 404 coming from deafult");
    break;
    }



    response.end();

});


server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Could it be because `/socket.html` does not equal `socket.html` ?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles I tried using /socket.html but it just displays a blank page with nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems.  The first is that the path doesn't match - it is `/socket.html`, not `socket.html`, so that's what you must put in your `case`.

Second, you are calling `response.end()` right after your `switch` statement, but the `/socket.html` case is asynchronous, so it hasn't finished at that point.  You should call `response.end()` separately in each `case` so that asynchronous actions are allowed to complete.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ahron. That was exactly the problem!